# Try to evaluate $\lim_{\alpha\to1^-}\frac{1}{\alpha(\alpha-1)}\left[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(\frac{y_i}{y^{'}}\right)^\alpha-1\right]$

Tags: calculus, limits

I can't evaluate this limit.
$$\lim_{\alpha\to1^-}\frac{1}{\alpha(\alpha-1)}\left[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(\frac{y_i}{y^{'}}\right)^\alpha-1\right]$$
where $y_i>0$, $y^{'}$ is the average of $y_i$

Comment: Please use `\lim` and `\sum`.

Comment: If $w_1=n_2=1/3$ and $w_2=n_1=2/3$, then the conditions are met, the sum is $1-(1/2)^{\alpha}+1-2^{\alpha}$ which goes to $-1/2$ as $\alpha\to1$, and the limit doesn't exist. Maybe it should be $\alpha\to0$?

Comment: Either that or $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m\frac{w_i}{n_i}=m$.

Comment: Note that my comment related to an earlier version of the problem. But there is still no reply to Antonio's questions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is one step in a financial essay.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I revise the formula

Comment: What happens if you try l'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: @GerryMyerson can I use it?

Comment: Well, you have the indeterminate form $0/0$, so I don't see why you can't use it. I haven't tried it myself, so I don't guarantee it will work, but it seems to me it's worth a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
\bar{y}=\frac1m\sum_{i=1}^my_i\quad\text{and}\quad x_i=\frac{y_i}{\bar{y}}
$$
Then
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{\alpha\to1^-}\frac{1}{\alpha(\alpha-1)}\left[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(\frac{y_i}{\bar{y}}\right)^\alpha-1\right]
&=\lim_{\alpha\to1^-}\frac{1}{\alpha-1}\left[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_i^\alpha-1\right]\\
&=\lim_{\alpha\to1^-}\frac{1}{\alpha-1}\left[\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(x_i^\alpha-x_i\right)\right]\\
&=\frac1m\sum_{i=1}^mx_i\log(x_i)\\
&=\frac1m\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{y_i}{\bar{y}}(\log(y_i)-\log(\bar{y}))\\
&=\frac{{\small\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m}\;y_i\log(y_i)}{{\small\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m}\;y_i}-\log(\bar{y})
\end{align}
$$
I don't see why this wouldn't work for $\alpha\to1^+$, too.